# Tab bar background color not changing in ios6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

I am working in a project and I need to implement tab bar controller in this. my tab bar background color is black and I used following code for this :

> ```
> [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];    
> UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
> UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
> UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
> UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];    
> [ tabBarItem1 setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2,0,-2,0)];
> [ tabBarItem2 setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2,0,-2,0)];
> [ tabBarItem3 setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2,0,-2,0)];
> [ tabBarItem4 setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2,0,-2,0)];
> ```

```
tabBarItem1.title=@"Home";
tabBarItem2.title=@"Connect";
tabBarItem3.title=@"About";
tabBarItem4.title=@"Settings";


[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIColor colorWithRed:139.0/255.0 green:189.0/255.0 blue:208.0 alpha:255.0], UITextAttributeTextColor,
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont,
  nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont,
  nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_icon_selected.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(24, 18)] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_icon.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(24, 18)]];

[tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"connect_icon_selected.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(24, 18)] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"connect_icon.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(24, 18)]];

[tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"about_icon_selected.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(24, 18)] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"about_icon.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(24, 18)]];

[tabBarItem4 setFinishedSelectedImage:[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_icon_selected.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(24, 18)] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_icon.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(24, 18)]];


self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

>

which is working fine in ios7 but there is no reflection of this line in ios6. Is there any thing else that I need to implement or any thing I missed regarding tab bar property in ios6? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well they changed a lot about colors in iOS 7. Read the human interface guidelines by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html

And here is the code:

```
//check if this is not iOS 7
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
//your code above except last line
//Tint is background in iOS 6 but text color in iOS 7
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}else{
//your code above
}
```